# Asked in interview round

Tags: algorithm, tree

Consider an undirected tree with N nodes, numbered from 1 to N. Each node has a label associated with it, which is an integer value. Different nodes can have the same label. Also, given a zero-indexed vector A of length N, where A[j] is the label value of the (j+1)-th node in the tree and a zero-indexed E of length K = (N-1) in which the edges of the tree are described (vector<pair<int,int>>E where E[i]={u,v} if there is edge between u and v ,0<=i<k). Find the number of  special path .
Special Path  follow following condition-

- starting node and end node of path path have same label but starting node should not equal to end node.
- All node present in path have label value<=label value of starting node.
- path length should greater than 1.The length is the number of nodes in that path.

N = 5

A= {1, 1, 1, 2, 2}

E= {{1, 2},{ 1, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}}

Output:
4

Explanation:

4->2->5 , 2->1 , 2->1->3 , 1->3

Constraints:

1≤N≤10^5, 1≤E≤N , 1≤A[i] ≤ 10^8

Answer (score 1):

By the constraints given, it looks like the interviewer is expecting an O(N<sup>2</sup>) answer, but you can actually do this in O(N log N) time using a [disjoint set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure):

First, sort the vertices by label, then initialize an empty disjoint set structure, and set an accumulator `total=0`.

Then, for each label **L**:

1. Initialize a singleton set for each vertex with label L, and merge it with all adjacent vertices that have smaller or equal labels.
2. Each root set will then represent a connected component of the subgraph with labels <= L.  Since the graph is a tree, so are these connected components, and there will be exactly one (simple) path between each pair of vertices in each one.  For each root set, let `nL` be the number of vertices with label L that it contains, and if it's non-zero, then `total += nL * (nL-1) / 2`, i.e., the number of pairs with both labels equal to L.